# why do File downloads get redirected to home page with vue.js history mode enabled on IIS

Tags: vue.js, iis, html5-history

I have the following setup: on IIS

A `Vue.js` app @ `https://localhost/some-app/`

I need to be able to download files from an inner folder:

`https://localhost/some-app/pdf-reports/test.pdf`

With vue.js `history mode` enabled and configured,
why do requests for inner folders or files get redirected to the home page?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Handle History Mode and custom 404/500" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: your current rule of IIS will redirect all pdf requests to '/'. One solution is adjust your rule to skip `some-app/pdf-reports/....pdf`. Another solution is uses axios or other http library to download the file first, then trigger download at the client.

Comment: @Sphinx first option works... thanks man